# c# Access проверка подключения при инициализации дизайнера

Tags: c#, access, проверка

Всем привет 
Такая ситуация: на форме есть датагрид, в него тянутся данные из mdb. База данных с паролем, на локальном сервере компании. При запуске программы внутри сети все хорошо запускается, но если запустить из внешней среды, то ошибка:
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Строка '\192.168.89.2\Volume_1***\Тимур\Управление складом\Склад.mdb' задает ошибочный путь.  Проверьте, что путь задан правильно и имеется подключение к серверу, на котором находятся файлы."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как осуществить проверку на подключение к БД до заполнения датагрида? В дизайнере вроде как нельзя свой код писать.

На всякий случай строка подключения: 
`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="\\192.168.89.2\Volume_1\***\Тимур\Управление складом\Склад.mdb";Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password= admin;`

Comment: А строка подключения в конфиге или прямо в программе где-то зашита?

Comment: ну, она есть в settings.settings (параметры проекта). также в тексте кода есть строка подключения, но она берет текст из параметров. как я понимаю, ошибка возникает на моменте инициализации формы и попытке заполнить датагрид